# How to serialize a list of Generic class in Unity with Json?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm using json to serialize my scene to text so I wrote this partial code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SceneComponent
{
    public string ComponentType;
    public string AssemblyName;
    public int ComponentID;
    
    public List<SceneProperty> SceneProperties;
}
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class SceneProperty
{
    public string PropertyPath;
    public string PropertyType;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class SceneProperty<T> : SceneProperty
{
    public T PropertyValue;

    public SceneProperty(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        PropertyPath = property.propertyPath;
        PropertyType = property.propertyType.ToString();
        PropertyValue = (T)GetValue(property);
    }

    protected static object GetValue(SerializedProperty property)
    {
         // not the actual implementation
         return (object)property.value;
    }
}
```

And I create my SceneComponent class lie this:

```
SceneComponent sc = new SceneComponent();
// filling sc other fields here then
sc.SceneProperties.Add(new SceneProperty<int>(property));
sc.SceneProperties.Add(new SceneProperty<bool>(property));
```

But when I serialize SceneComponent class with unity JsonUtility this is a similar result I get and my SceneProperties list is not serialized at all. So can you help me to serialize this list?

```
"SceneComponents": [
        {
          "ComponentType": "UnityEngine.Transform",
          "AssemblyName": "UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
          "ComponentID": -2828
        },
        {
          "ComponentType": "VirtualCamera",
          "AssemblyName": "Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
          "ComponentID": -5130
        }
      ]
```

Comment: JsonUtility is very outdated. Install  Newtonsoft.Json for unity. There are samples how to use it too.

Comment: Yup, I test the Newtonsoft.Json which is internal now and It did a better job. thanks @Serge

Comment: In `.Net (Core) 3.0` and beyond you can also use the classes in the `System.Text.Json` namespace